# Gun v0.9.92 using SEA : Can't put nested data when not logged in

Tags: gun

I'm using ( well...experimenting actually ) with SEA. Everything auth related is working great...But...

I can no longer put anything in Gun if i'm NOT logged in.

`user.get('mydata').get('level1').get('level2').put('yup')` works

`user.leave()`

`gun.get('mydata').get('level1').get('level2').put('yup')`

returns "NO! Soul is not signed at 'level1'. "

Is this intentional ?
Because what if i want to put data in gun that is not user bound?

Answer (score 0):

@stef-de-vries great question!

Yes, SEA "firewalls" all data and requires it come from a verifiable source (a user).

By default (although you can change this, see below), it does not allow for any "public" data. This is because if it did allow it, that may allow malicious peers to spam, DDoS, or exploit data.

If you enable SEA and want to explicitly allow for public data, you need to use the security hook:

```
var gun = Gun();

gun.on('secure', function(msg){
    var yes;
    /* enforce some rules about data */
    /* requires wire-spec understanding */
    if(yes){
        this.to.next(msg); // call next middleware
    }
    // NOT calling next middleware firewalls the data.
});
```

We recommend creating a strict schema, and then use the schema to enforce the security on the data.

> **Note**: If you want the "plaintext" version of SEA data from the wire spec message graph, you can call `Gun.SEA.read(data, false, plaintext => console.log(plaintext))` the `false` means it won't try to verify the signature on the data since it is leaving it to you to verify if it is secure through other means.

Also, since SEA is in alpha, things might change or the security hook might be implemented incorrectly. So please do complain if it doesn't work as expected, or give feedback on any better ways or ideas to handle this.

For instance, in the future, I think it will be possible to create a framework built on top of the security hook, that would have a super easy developer facing API that is based on the developer's schema. Basically, the developer would just annotate their schema with security policies, and then this-future-framework would just automatically create the appropriate security hooks internally, without you having to code it.